# TypeError: Cannot read property 'enableLatestRenderer' of null, js engine: hermes in React Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, error-handling, metro-bundler, react-native-hermes

I have react-native app with "0.64.1" version. After launch on Android I get two errors on terminal after metro bundler start:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'enableLatestRenderer' of null, js engine: hermes
Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. 
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

On IOS app launch without this errors and works fine. This is my environment info:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.2.1
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
    Memory: 708.67 MB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.18.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.17 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.15 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.06.13.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK: Not Found
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738
    Xcode: /undefined - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 17.0.2 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: Not Found
    react-native: Not Found
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

What I tried:

```
// Killed node
killall -9 node

// Clear cache
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

But nothing works for me.